# How is it possible to input a string into an array of pointers to character?

Tags: c

My problem is how is it possible to input a string into an array of character pointers? Is memory being dynamically allocated here or something? What is actually getting stored in the array '`name`'?

```
char *name[20];
printf("Enter a string:");
scanf("%s",name);
printf("%s",name);
```

This code works fine. It prints the string I enter. How is it possible to treat `char *name[20]` just like `char name[20]`?

Comment: When you use scanf or printf you are responsible for getting the types right. There is no intrinsic type checking for the arguments. Use a debugger to see where the scanf results are being stored. It isn't what you think.

Comment: C compilers trust that the programmer knows what they're doing — even when they write code that shows they don't.  They won't stop them from doing things that aren't sensible; they'll do the best they can to make it 'work'.  And they often don't warn about the problems unless asked to do so.

Answer (score 2):

> Is memory being dynamically allocated here or something?

No.

> This code works fine. It prints the string I enter. How is it possible to treat char *name[20] just like char name[20]?

The behaviour of the program is undefined.

It is undefined, because it violates the requirements of the `scanf` and `printf` functions.

The C standard says of `%s` specifier for both `scanf` and `printf` (quoting the standard draft document N1570):

> the  corresponding  argument  shall  be  a pointer  to  the  initial  element  of  a  character  array ...

`name` is **not** a pointer to the initial element of a character array. It is (actually an array, but) after decaying, a pointer to an initial pointer to character in an array of pointers to characters. Thus the requirements are violated and behaviour of the program is undefined.

> what did you mean by "behaviour is undefined"?

It means that nothing about the behaviour of the program is guaranteed. As far as the language is concerned, the program might:

- Produce output that you expect.
- Produce output that you didn't expect.
- Produce output that you want to be produced.
- Produce some output that you didn't want.
- Not produce output at all.
- Crash
- Not crash
- Behave differently on another system.
- Behave differently on the same system.
- Behave differently when you're debugging it.
- Behave differently only when you are on vacation.
- Behave differently for any reason possible.
- Behave differently for seemingly no reason at all.
- Behave the same always
- Behave exactly the same as if you had used `char name[20]` despite not having used it.
- Not behave like that.
- Have any behaviour whatsoever.

Undefined behaviour is to be avoided.

Comment: what did you mean by "behaviour of the program is undefined"?

Comment: yes. but why is char *name[20] being treated like char name[20]?

Comment: @SnowVilliers Why do you think that char *name[20] is being treated like char name[20]?

Comment: That answer is correct, but it's not really helpful, because it does not accurately describe why and how the code displays undefined behavior.

Comment: @eerorika because they both are working like they are the same. Although in the memory something else is being stored I believe. I wanted to know why strings are being stored in an array of pointers. I tried printing the values of name. eg printf("%c",name[0]); it gives me the first character of the string i input. but when i try this code : printf("%c",name[1]); it gives me the 5th character of the string i input.

Comment: So what you mean is that the output is compiler dependent? So, some compiler might treat char *name[20] like char name[20] and some might not? And so this type of code should be avoided? BTW i was using gcc 32-bit.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel I added *why*. There isn't really a comprehensive *how* answer, since the behaviour is not specified anywhere and not guaranteed to be same everywhere (nor different). Frankly, I find it pointless to consider.

Comment: @SnowVilliers The behaviour can depend on absolutely anything, including the compiler. All compilers can treat the program in any way they choose. `And so this type of code should be avoided?` Very much yes. When the language standard says that your program **shall** do something, it would be foolish not to.

Comment: @SnowVilliers — If you're using GCC, it can be made to give warnings about your abuse of `scanf()` and `printf()`.  Use `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror …` along with whatever other options you were using before.  The `-Werror` option means you won't be able to ignore what would otherwise be warnings; they're treated as errors.  The other two enable extensive sets of warnings.  I don't normally run code that won't compile with those options in use — life's too short to bother with bad code when the compiler can tell me about bugs in the code (and it reports bugs in your code).

Comment: @SnowVilliers It absolutely should be avoided. Yes, different compilers might generate code that behaves differently. Some might generate code that behaves as if you have a char array instead of a pointer array. But the same compiler might also generate code that behaves differently every time you run it. Or it might generate code that prints out Shakespeare poems. It's not just dependent on the compiler. As far as the C++ standard is concerned, your code could do anything, any time.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Also `-pedantic` in case portability is a concern :)

Comment: I finally understand now. Thanks to all of you. :)

Answer (score 2):

`scanf` and `printf` expected an array of characters, but you gave it an array of pointers. However, they can't tell the difference because they are variadic. This causes undefined behavior, so anything is possible.

What likely happened here is that `scanf` simply wrote the characters into the memory of the pointer array and `printf` treated the data as characters because neither of the functions know that the chunk of memory you gave it is supposed to store pointers instead of characters. Printing out the second element gave you the fifth character likely because your system has four byte pointers, so the second pointer element starts at the fifth byte and therefore a fifth character.

Again, your code exhibits undefined behavior, so the previous paragraph is only speculation. None of this is guaranteed by the standard and you shouldn't rely on it, ever.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you for the help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Although [eerorika’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57016048/6671104) is perfectly correct, from what I feel OP may need some more detailed explanation of what’s going on here…

What you declare with your `char * name[20]` is **NOT** an *array that points to 20 characters*. It **IS** *an array of 20 pointers to memory* (each pointer is treated as pointing to a character or an array of characters). The `[20]` in the declaration already specifies that you need 20 elements, and what is preceeding (`char *` in your case) specifies what these elemnts are. So the correct declaration(in your context) is simply `char name[20]`.

Now the compiler sees that you need a block of memory of 20 characters and it reserves the memory for you (on stack, no dynamic allocation here). Then `char name[20]` is a continuous block of reserved memory that can hold 20 characters.

You get an address to the beginning of this block as `&name[0]` or simply `name`. The latter only since a static array variable – which is the entire block of 20 chars in your case – is implicitly **convertible** (not identical to) a pointer to the beginning of that block of memory, i.e. `char *`. (If you feel like you do not understand this last statement, you may consult e.g. this [short article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/whats-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c/) or google around a bit,e.g., on *difference between char array and char pointer in c*.

The following illustrates what happens with the correct code and what with yours and why it is undefined behaviour (UB) and why it (un)luckily works in your case.

With the correct declaration `char name[20]` you get

[char [20] memory block uninitialized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baLVu.png)

`?character` means that the content in every cell of the buffer is not yet specified but the compiler treat it as a character.

When you pass this into `scanf` and a user enters, say, "HelloKitty", this answer will be filled into the `char [20]` block of memory reserved by the compiller.

[char [20] memory block after passing it to scanf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQg72.png)

That's what you want to get.

Now here is what you actually get with your `char * name[20]` declaration. At the beginign the situation is like this

[char * [20] memory block uninitialized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRNSm.png)

`?pointer` means that the content in every cell of the buffer is not yet specified but the compiler treat it as a **pointer to character**.

When you pass this into `scanf` and the user enters theirs "HelloKitty" this answer will be filled into the `char * [20]` block of memory reserved by the compiller as previously.

Now more attention is needed. This is possible only due to the fact that `scanf` is not type-safe. It takes whatever adress it gets (the address of `name[0]` in your case) and fill it in carelessly, according to what its `format specifiers` specify. So it hapilly fill an array of characters into a block of memory that is supposed to contain an array of poiners. Now, every character has a binary representation, indeed. So what happens under the hood is that the `char * [20]` memory block will be filled in with "zeros and ones" that represent the string "HelloKitty" (up to the length of that string).

[char * [20] memory block after passing it to scanf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozyvl.png)

`?!pointer` means that the content is still treated as a **pointer to character** by the compiller, yet the value of that pointer (the address it technically points to) has been rewritten by calling `scanf`. (note: even though "HelloKitty" contains 11 characters including the terminating nul, not 11 cells are rewritten since `sizeof` each cell equals `sizeof` of a pointer. Typically `sizeof` of a pointer is 4 times that of `char` on a 32bit architecture, so only 2 cells and a part of the third one wil be rewritten)

Now why it all works fine for you is just because `printf` is just as ignorant of its actual types as its sister `scanf`. So `printf` takes the address of `name[0]` and (re)interpret its "zeros and ones" (back) to the "HelloKitty" string.

Practically, your program will not likely (see below) invoke UB, as long as you pass the `name` variable  between `printf` and `scanf` (or like functions) only. The (binary) content of the memory block reserved for `char * name[20]` is somewhat (see below) guaranteed to be eqivalent to the (binary representation of) the "HelloKitty" string. As long as the content read by `scanf` does not exceed the memory block provided to it, the program does not get likely (see below) corrupted in any way. You may just as well write `int i; scanf("%s",&i); printf("%s",&i);` and the program will (likely) work fine as long as the user eneters less than 3 characters as an input. (supposing `sizeof` `int` is 4 `chars`))

Technically, you code falls in UB. This is just what the standard says. The standard cannot treat every single case of "when the code would actually work if the programmer write something weird". And yes, treating `char * [20]` as `char [20]` in `scanf` is "something weird." Simultaneously, by specifying something UB, the standard gives some freedom to compiler implementers. If you were to write a compiler, you may decide to parse the format in `scanf` compile-time and generate a special set of instructions that **rely** on the fact that correct type is provided for `name` (the fact that I can hardly imagine such scenario - at least for the `%s` switcher - does not change anything).  So the program is UB. Period. :)

ps.> Consider using `scanf("%20s", name)` in your code. This will prevent `scanf` from reading characters beyond the length of the memory block, which would result in yet another UB.